# How to calculate the ratio by calculated field in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field, tableau-desktop

This is a sample of my dataset:

| account name | connected_users | id | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 5 | 1012 | ACCEPTED |
| x | 5 | 1015 | ACCEPTED |
| x | 5 | 1013 | DELETED |
| y | 32 | 20145 | DELETED |
| y | 32 | 20146 | DELETED |
| y | 32 | 20147 | DELETED |
| y | 32 | 20148 | ACCEPTED |
| y | 32 | 20149 | ACCEPTED |

And I want to calculate the acceptance rate as following in Tableau:

Acceptance rate = (Count (distinct accepted ids) +connected user)/ (Count (distinct all ids) +connected user)

In this way for account x ==> Acceptance rate = (2+5)/(3+5)=87.5%
account y ==> Acceptance rate = (2+32)/(5+32)=91.9%

And the acceptance rate in general (Grand total) should be : (32+5+2+2)/(32+5+3+5)=91.1%

How can I do that with a calculated field in Tableau ?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter within an aggregate.

```
(COUNTD(IF [STATUS]='ACCEPTED' THEN [ID] END) + COUNT([CONNECTED_USER]))
/
(COUNTD([ID]) + COUNT([CONNECTED_USER]))
```